# Precautions to Secure Java Coding

Tags: java, security

I am looking to gather some professional advises and precautions to do Secure Coding using Java. Couple of them I am already considering:

- Should not log unwanted/excessive/sensitive information.
- SQL injection should be taken care in parameterised queries, should use `PreparedStatement` or `CallableStatement` instead of `Statement`.
- All the resources (db connections, input/output streams) should be release carefully.
- Internal Exceptions should be caught and sanitized before propagating to upstream callers as it may reveal sensitive information.
- Should clear the sensitive information even from memory when done as it can appear in core dump.
- In case of inter-process communication, sensitive arguments should be encrypted.
- Should use `private` for variables unless having good reason not to.
- Should provide copy methods for sensitive classes.
- Should prefer static factory method for object construction over public constructor.
- Should avoid serialization of class that might hold sensitive information.

Appreciate any add up from the community.

Comment: You should use ESAPI; Furher information https://www.owasp.org/index.php/ESAPI

Comment: I think you want to be clear about the context. Injection attacks dealing with SQL is very different (though may intersect) contexts where having fields private (or default access) is important for security.

Comment: Also see [The CERT Oracle Secure Coding Standard for Java](https://www.securecoding.cert.org/confluence/display/java/The+CERT+Oracle+Secure+Coding+Standard+for+Java).

Answer (score 2):

Just another that comes to mind, you should use defensive copies when returning from a getter method.

If you're looking to protect your released code, you could consider something like [JET](http://www.excelsiorjet.com/) although that's not quite what your question is asking I thought I'd just mention it.

Comment: JET is more related to code obfuscation

Comment: Yes, it is, but I mentioned it just for reference as it seemed relevant.